# SHA256 Unix style hash with javascript

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to generate a SHA256
Hash according to unix shadow format.
I know I can create SHA256 hashes with crypto.subtle.digest, but that has not the format that I need.

Hash looks like this bellow, so I need to create the hash with an salt and 5000 rounds that follow the algorithm described [here](https://www.akkadia.org/drepper/SHA-crypt.txt) the use a different base64 alphabet and the encoded password is 43 long and has dots in it.

```
$5$r.ba0aYa2PI.$2Yq2P8t.dKkIT3ZAnxg.y6J2LYD1p7N0NhSzQhL9Zy3

               < ---------- Encoded Password ------------->
```

Implementing this itself looks pain  for me

Comment: Asking for software recommendations is off-topic

Comment: `SHA265`, do you mean `SHA256`?

Comment: `Is there any JS library`, it's not needed, Cryptographic encoding / decoding is built into browsers these days, -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Crypto

Comment: Upsi Typo, i mean SHA256, i Know that with Crypto API as I wrote, but thats just an regular SHA256 Hash.